# Spring Security and RESTful API layer

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, architecture, restful-architecture

In my Spring Boot application I have implemented RESTful API layer. I have secured this API with a plain `JSESSIONID` + CSRF protection.

I'll use HTTP Sessions only as a container for the authentication information.

In future, for High Availability in a clustered environment, I plan to use Spring Session Redis for application horizontal scaling.

Right now I am in doubt about this architecture. At this very early stage  whether I should to leave everything as is or do I need to re-implement this approach using token based solution like for example JWT?